# Symbolizing File Geodatabase feature class with Layer File created from AutoCAD drawing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, export, file-geodatabase, autocad

I received an autocad drawing file which I converted into feature classes with the CAD to Geodatabase tool.

**I would like to symbolize the exported data in ArcMap the same way it was symbolized in the input drawing file I received.**

I visualized the drawing file in ArcMap and saved the "Drawing layers" Layer files as per usual but I am unable to import this symbology into the exported layer properties.

When I import the saved layer files, the resulting "Import Symbology Matching Dialog" correctly matches all 3 fields (Linetype, Colo, LineWt) but clicking OK doesn't do anything - dialog disappears and symbology remains unchanged.

Alternatively, when I load the layer file itself, it is linked with the DWG and source can only be changed for the CAD Feature Class type.

How can i symbolize my exported data the same way as the original DWG is shown in ArcMap.

Comment: That's totally strange.. what would happen if you added the CAD layers and then changed the data source to the geodatabase?

Comment: As I mentioned above - can't do that. The only data source option there is a "CAD Feature Class" type. Can't even choose anything else.