# Export to CAD from Arcgis while preserving the symbology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, symbology, feature-class, cad

Is there a way or tool that you can export layers (feature classes - points, lines and polygons) from Arcgis desktop 10.1 into a DWG/DXF, while still preserving the symbol (basic symbol - colours and basic shapes) from Arcgis?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if it can be done it'll probably be in [FME](http://www.safe.com/). I know there are ways to add styles to a dwg (more or less manually), but not if you can read them from ArcMap.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am working with an engineer remotely who wants me to send him shapefiles with symbology and I have not had any luck.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/98953)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/98953)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with ArcGIS.  I asked a similar question here: [Symbolizing File Geodatabase feature class with Layer File created from AutoCAD drawing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103996/symbolizing-file-geodatabase-feature-class-with-layer-file-created-from-autocad)

Personally, I was at least hoping to create a layer file from the CAD drawing that was added to ArcMap (similar symbology to what it appears like in AutoCAD but not identical).  Although saving CAD layer works, it cannot be imported into a FGDB feature class layer even though the data and field structure was actually imported from the very same AutoCAD file.  When you look at the properties of the CAD layer added to ArcMap it containes an additional symbology category under its symbology categories: **CAD Unique Entity Values**.  Importing symbology from layer saved from CAD file doesn't raise any errors but it simply will not import anything. The only way I know of to do this is the labour intensive manual way.  The problem is compounded by the fact that when ArcMap loads the CAD file and brings over the symbology, it uses categories with 3 fields: Linetype, Color and LIneWt.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to export from GIS to CAD with symbology and labeling too. You have to export first your GIS layers into a personal GDB, adding some key fields that the standard ArcGIS toolbox (ToCAD) will read and asign the defined symbology, depending on the values populated into the fields created in the previous step. 
You can place everything into a custom Toolbox, and run it anytime.
If you need more information I posted two weeks ago more details regarding this matter in [my blog](https://gisassetmanagement.blogspot.com.es/2016/10/exportar-capas-gis-formato-cad.html?m=1). The blog is writen in spanish, if you need more details please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

SmartExporter.DXF for ArcMap works pretty well - http://www.gisexpertsolutions.com, however is not free.

Comment: Are you affiliated with that website/tool?

Answer (score 0):

Try to export the map as pdf using ArcMap, then use the PDF import option in Autocad to load that map. It will keep all of the atributtes you have used in the symbology, and even be editable in Autocad. It's easier than you think